# Custom IEnumerator in F#

Tags: f#

More F# questions. I have the implementation of a binary reader below. I want it to work like an enumerable sequence. The code below gives me the following error and I have as usual no clue how to resolve it. I have a c# implementation where I had to implement two different overrides for `.Current` property. I guess I have to do the same here but not sure how. As always, thanks a million in advance for your help.

> error FS0366: No implementation was given for `Collections.IEnumerator.get_Current() : obj`. Note that all interface members must be implemented and listed under an appropriate `interface` declaration, e.g. `interface ... with member ...`.

```
namespace persisitence
open System.Collections.Generic
open System
open System.IO
type BinaryPersistenceIn<'T>(fn: string, serializer: ('T * BinaryReader) -> unit) as this =
    let stream_ = File.Open(fn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    let reader_ = new BinaryReader(stream_)
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable current_ : 'T

    let eof() =
         stream_.Position = stream_.Length


    interface IEnumerator<'T> with

        member this.MoveNext() = 
            let mutable ret = eof()

            if stream_.CanRead && ret then
                serializer(this.current_, reader_)

            ret

        member this.Current
            with get() = this.current_ 

        member this.Dispose() =
            stream_.Close()
            reader_.Close()

        member this.Reset() = 
            stream_.Seek((int64) 0., SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Richard pointed out, you need to implement `IEnumerator.Current`.
Here's code in response to your question "how to do it". This should work:

A few notes: (thanks to @DaxFohl)

- `IEnumerator` is in different namespace (see code).
- `MoveNext` and `Reset` are really members of `IEnumerator`, not `IEnumerator<'t>`, so that's where they should be implemented.
- `Dispose`, however, is on `IEnumerator<'t>` (surprise! :-)

-

```
type BinaryPersistenceIn<'T>(fn: string, serializer: ('T * BinaryReader) -> unit) as this =
    ...    

    interface IEnumerator<'T> with
        ...
        member this.Current
            with get() = this.current_ 

    interface System.Collections.IEnumerator with
        member this.Current
            with get() = this.current_ :> obj
        member this.MoveNext() = ...
        member this.Reset() = ...
```

And in conclusion, I must add this: are you really *sure* you want to implement `IEnumerator`? This is a rather low-lever thing, easy to get wrong. Why not use a sequence computation expression instead?

```
let binaryPersistenceSeq (fn: string) (serializer: BinaryReader -> 'T) = 
  seq {
    use stream_ = File.Open(fn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    use reader_ = new BinaryReader(stream_)

    let eof() = stream_.Position = stream_.Length

    while not eof() do
       if stream_.CanRead then
          yield serializer reader_
  }
```

Comment: note `IEnumerator` is in `System.Collections`, not `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: Also note `Reset` and `MoveNext` should be defined in the non-generic interface instead of the generic one.

Comment: @Fyodor The solution you proposed gives me the following error: C:\Dev\ATF\framework\persisitence\persistence.fs(74,15): error FS0033: The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<_>' expects 1 type argument(s) but is given 0. However when I do implement another Current returning an obj type as you have cast it works.

Comment: @rk540 see my first comment.

Comment: @rk540 It gives you this error because `IEnumerator` is in different namespace! So that when you just type `IEnumerator`, the compiler thinks you're referring to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator` rather than `System.Collections.IEnumerator`. Use namespace-qualified name.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerator<T>` extends [`IEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) and `IEnumerator` has a `Current` property of type `object`.

You need to also implement [`IEnumerator.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current.aspx) separately from `IEnumerator<T>.Current`.

Comment: Thanks to @FyodorSoikin for the s/IEnumerable/IEnumerator/ !

Comment: That is my problem. Not certain how to do so. When I add another interface IEnumerable<'T> and implement a Current member I get a illegal override error.

Answer (score 0):

This version of the code compiles... as to does it really work.. will find out.

```
type BinaryPersistenceIn<'T>(fn: string, serializer: ('T * BinaryReader) -> unit) =
let stream_ = File.Open(fn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
let reader_ = new BinaryReader(stream_)
[<DefaultValue>] val mutable current_ : 'T

let eof() =
     stream_.Position = stream_.Length


interface IEnumerator<'T> with

    member this.MoveNext() = 
        let mutable ret = eof()

        if stream_.CanRead && ret then
            serializer(this.current_, reader_)

        ret

    member this.Current
        with get() = this.current_ 

    member this.Dispose() =
        stream_.Close()
        reader_.Close()

    member this.Reset() = 
        stream_.Seek((int64) 0., SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore

    member this.Current
        with get() = this.current_ :> obj
```