# IEnumerator in F# continued

Tags: f#

This is the question about the earlier `Persistence` class that I was trying to expose as an enumerator. I realized that I need to pass by reference really to change the value of of the object that I am trying to populate. I guess I am going about this in a C++ way (As most may have guessed I am an F# beginner). However, I want to be as efficient in terms of memory foot print as I can. Ideally I would like to reuse the same object over and over again when I read from a file.

I am having a problem with this code where it does not allow me to pass by reference in the call to the function `serialize`. I am again reproducing the code here. I thank you in advance for your help.

The error I get:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type `byref<'T>` but here has type `'T`

If I change the call to `serialize(& current_, reader_)` I get the following error:

> `persistence.fs(71,6)`: error FS0437: A type would store a `byref` typed value. This is not permitted by Common IL.
>   `persistence.fs(100,29)`: error FS0412: A type instantiation involves a `byref` type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.
>   `persistence.fs(100,30)`: error FS0423: The address of the field `current_` cannot be used at this point

The CODE:

```
type BinaryPersistenceIn<'T when 'T: (new : unit -> 'T)>(fn: string, serializer: ('T byref * BinaryReader) -> unit) =
let stream_ = File.Open(fn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
let reader_ = new BinaryReader(stream_)
let mutable current_ = new 'T()

let eof() =
     stream_.Position = stream_.Length


interface IEnumerator<'T> with

    member this.Current
        with get() = current_ 

    member this.Dispose() =
        stream_.Close()
        reader_.Close() 

interface System.Collections.IEnumerator with

    member this.Current
        with get() = current_ :> obj

    member this.Reset() = 
        stream_.Seek((int64) 0., SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore

    member this.MoveNext() = 
        let mutable ret = eof()
        if stream_.CanRead && ret then
            serializer( current_, reader_)

        ret
```

Comment: Do you really have to have it as a class? What about my proposal with `seq` computation expression from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30128698/180286

Comment: AAH I did not notice your sequence oriented approach... Let me check it out.

Comment: @Fyodor, The reason I did not use the stream / sequence idea is that I did not want to allocate a struct every time. I am reading a tick data base and it tends to slow the reads down as time goes on.

Comment: What struct does it allocate, where?

Answer (score 1):

You can circumvent this by introducing a mutable local, passing it to `serialize`, and then assigning back to `current_`:

```
 member this.MoveNext() = 
    let mutable ret = eof()
    if stream_.CanRead && ret then
        let mutable deserialized = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
        serializer( &deserialized, reader_)
        current_ <- deserialized

    ret
```

But now this is becoming really, *really* unsettling. Notice the use of `Unchecked.defaultof<_>`? There is no other way to initialize a value of unknown type, and it's called "unchecked" for a reason: the compiler can't guarantee safety of this code.

I strongly advise that you explore other ways of achieving your initial goal, such as using a `seq` computation expression instead, as I have [suggested in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128698/180286).

Comment: I like your sequence expression. But I have noticed that with my C# reader that allocates a struct on de-serialize it slows down with time.

Comment: I assume with struct you are referring to is a `'T` (which can be struct). Now I find that a bit strange as you are implicitly creating a new struct when calling Current as a struct in .NET have value semantics. That means Current will create a copy. It would make more sense to me that is slowed down over time if you were allocating more and more "classes" as they are "heap" objects and thus needs GC:ing.

Comment: The main problem with `Unchecked.defaultof<>` is that it will return `null` values for F# reference types that doesn't allow null literals. It's not as as "bad" as `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` which returns a non-constructed object.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to memory footprint, let's analyze the sequence option:

- You have an instance of the `seq`. That's going to be some class implementing `IEnumerable<'T>`. This one will be held until you no longer need the seq, i.e. not reallocated each time.
- You hold a `Stream` as part of the `seq`, with the same lifetime.
- You hold a `BinaryReader` as part of the `seq`, with the same lifetime.
- `eof : unit -> bool` is a compiler-generated function class as part of the `seq`, with the same lifetime.
- The loop will use a `bool` for the while loop and the `if` condition. Both of which are stack-allocated structs and needed for the branching logic.
- And finally, you `yield` an instance that you already got from the serializer.

Conceptually, that's as little memory consumption as you can have for a lazily evaluated `seq`. Once an element is consumed, it can be garbage collected. Multiple evaluations will do the same thing again.

The only thing you can actually play with, is what the serializer returns.

If you have your serializer return a struct, it is copied and stack-allocated. And it should not be mutable. Mutable structs discouraged. [Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Structs are good with respect to the garbage collector as they avoid garbage collection. But they are typically to be used with very small objects, in the order of say 16-24 bytes max.

Classes are heap-allocated and are passed by reference always. So if your serializer returns a class, say a string, then you just pass that around by reference and overhead of copying will be very small as you only ever copy the reference, not the content.

If you want your serializer side-effecting, i.e. overwriting the same object (class, i.e. reference type is to be used for this), then the whole approach of `IEnumerable<'T>` and consequently `seq` is wrong. `IEnumerable`s always give you new objects as result and should never modify any pre-existing object. The only state with them should be the information, at what place in the enumeration they are.

So if you need a side-effecting version, you could do something like (pseudo-code).

```
let readAndOverwrite stream target =
    let position = // do something here to know the state
    fun target -> 
        target.MyProp1 <- stream.ReadInt()
        target.MyProp2 <- stream.ReadFloat()
```

Passing as `byref` does not seem very reasonable to me, as you then anyway allocate and garbage collect the object. So you can just as well do that in an immutable way. What you can do, is just modifying properties on your object instead.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about lifetime of the stream. It will be created anew for every new enumeration. Which exactly matches the OP's class-based implementation. You can think of the `seq` itself as corresponding to the class (with bound constructor arguments) and of enumerators produced from it as corresponding to instances of the class.

Comment: @Daniel Fabian, Thank you for your comments and elaboration. I will look into your proposal of readAndOverwrite. I like it and seems really elegant. So you suggest that I return a function. Given that I am an F# and functional programming novice. It will be a bit before I digest your solution and implement it.

Comment: @Daniel Fabian, I read the article "why mutable structs are evil?" and Mr. Lipperts article as well. I actually think his conclusion is wrong. Instead of advocating care when using structs, branding them as evil is not the right approach. I do not understand the notion of a non-mutable struct. What is that? A struct vs a class/type in my mind (forgive my C++ perspective) is that one has encapsulation and the other does not. The boundary should not be breached.

Comment: A struct, in .net is a value type, whereas a class is a reference type. That is different from C++. And a mutable struct, would be a value type, i.e. copy semantics, that allows mutation. Think say a point with x and y components where you can modify a coordinate. An immutable point on the other hand would mean, that you create a new struct with changed values instead.

Comment: @Daniel, I lost you when you said "A mutable struct, would be a value type", are value types in .net immutable? (immutability enforced by language) not really. If I understand it correctly, value type implies one important thing, they are copied around on assignment. I do not understand where immutability enters the picture.

Comment: Well, the whole point of just not mutating structs is about it not behaving in an intuitive way. When you modify an object, you'd expect every reference of it to be modified, which happens if you do it with classes. Mutating a struct, however, would only change your local copy. That's why it is suggested to not make mutable structs. All typical structs like DateTime, int, long, float, etc. are always immutable, i.e. the struct is written in such a way, that once created, you cannot modify the value.